# How to get JSON data very fast from URL in windows phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone-8.1

I am developing one windows phone app.

In this app I am getting JSON data from service URL and binding to list box. And, in this JSON data has 2500 cities. These cities came from service and binding to  list box take 5 minutes time.

Then how to getting data very fast from service? please help me.

Below is the code:

```
 public async void insertcities()
        {
            try
            {


                await this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                {


                    var busclient = new Newpavanapp.JsonWebClient();

                    var Busresp1 = await busclient.DoRequestAsync(Url.weburl + "getCities");
                    string Busresult1 = Busresp1.ReadToEnd();
                    JArray BusjsonArray = JArray.Parse(Busresult1);

                    for (int j = 0; j < BusjsonArray.Count; j++)
                    {

                        JObject jobj = (JObject)BusjsonArray[j];

                        string id = (string)jobj["cityid"];
                        string cityname = (string)jobj["cityname"];



                        city cit = new city();
                        cit.cityname = cityname;

                        Fromcityname1.Items.Add(cityname);
                        Tocityname1.Items.Add(cityname);
                        Db_Helper.Insert(new Buscities(id, cityname));
                        UserProfileList.Add(cit);

                        //  citieslist.Add(cityname);

                    }



                });
```

Comment: Anyone please help me.Iam working on this last one week,still iam not getting answer.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so first: Your code fragment isn't enough to reproduce problem, but i think your code to getting data is fine and you have problem with binding.

You wrote:

> These cities came from service and binding to list box take 5 minutes time.

Check, how much time you need for download data without binding. Because probably binding is the most time-consuming operation. If you try to bind 2500 elements and you don't use virtualization it can be problem on windows phone. Try to use [listview with virtualization (it can be helpful)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alainza/archive/2014/09/04/listview-basics-and-virtualization-concepts.aspx).

**@Update (17:30 - 12.10.2015)**

> yes.its download data fast.but whenever binding the data that time
>   only taking time.then what should i do.please help me.please give me
>   any sample.

Ok, so in my opinion:
You shouldn't bind all elements in same time. Read about incremental loading in listbox ([Load more items into ListBox when scrolled to bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9958138/load-more-items-into-listbox-when-scrolled-to-bottom)). You can download all items, and add to itemssource only part of them, and after user scroll to end load more.

Comment: yes.its  download data fast.but whenever binding the data that time only taking time.then what should i do.please help me.please give me any sample.